# Running ros joint state publisher ends up with no executable found

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ros, robotics

I want to run

```
ros2 run joint_state_publisher_gui joint_state_publisher_gui
```

when I run it, it says “no executable found”.

How would I fix this?

I've tried searching online for some answers, but couldn't find any. I've also asked people in the official ROS discord server, but no one has replied yet.

Comment: Is this a package you built or should be already installed? Probably you are missing to source the environment like `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the package installed correctly? If not, install with

> sudo apt install ros-foxy-joint-state-publisher-gui

If you receive a message that the package is already installed, make sure you source your distribution with

> source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash

Answer (score 0):

Also

ros2 pkg list

ros2 pkg executables

might be helpful letting you know if the package is even there.